# Curl command not working with parameters which has comma separated values

Tags: python, shell, unix, jenkins, curl

Curl command not working with parameters which has comma separated values. For example, `curl -X POST -u user:pwd  "http://jenkinsurl:port/view/IM-BigData/job/workspace/job/bigdata/buildWithParameters?environment=DEV&operation=multi_input&activity=MAP_TO_DB,MAP_TO_URI,MAP_TO_GRP&privilege=ALL&permission=GRANT&rl_name=rl_name&grouped_input=db_name,hdfs://nameservice1/<parentpath>/data/dbname.db,,,group_name,rl_name&requester_id=id&rm_ticket_no=RM12345&LANID=lanid&INTERNALPASS=abc"`

Comment: "Not working" is not a fixable problem. Please specify *how* it fails and what you would expect it to do instead.

Comment: <a href="https://jenkins.io/redirect/users-mailing-list">The users list</a> might be also useful in understanding what has happened.</p><h2>Stack trace</h2><pre style="margin:2em; clear:both">java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal choice for parameter activity: MAP_TO_DB,MAP_TO_URI,MAP_TO_GRP

I got it. This is due to choice parameter which is allow one parameter at a time

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is not the commas but the slashes.  Try url-encoding the parameter values.

More info at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding)

Comment: This is due to choice parameter. I fixed it. Thank you.